# Sorting with abstract class

Tags: java, sorting

I had some difficulties in sorting in decreasing order the elements of the following abstract class and its extensions.

```
package BankServices;

public abstract class Operation {

       public Operation (int date, double value){
       }
       public abstract double getValue();
       public abstract int getDate();
       public abstract String toString();
}

package BankServices;

public class Deposit extends Operation {
private int date;
private int value;

public Deposit(int date, double value) {
    super(date, value);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return date + "," + value + "+";
}

@Override
public double getValue() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return value;
}

@Override
public int getDate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return date;
}
}
package BankServices;

public class Withdrawal extends Operation{
private int date;
private double value;

public Withdrawal(int date, double value) {
    super(date, value);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return date + "," + value + "-";
}

@Override
public double getValue() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return value;
}

@Override
public int getDate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return date;
}   
}
```

I had to implement these methods of the main class returning sorted lists in descending order:

```
public List<Operation> getMovements() {
    Collections.sort(operations, new Comparator<Operation>(){
        public int compare(Operation a, Operation b){
            return (int) (b.getDate() - a.getDate());
        }
    });
    return operations;
}

public List<Deposit> getDeposits() {
    Collections.sort(deposits, new Comparator<Operation>(){
        public int compare(Operation a, Operation b){
            return (int) (b.getValue() - a.getValue());
        }
    });
    return deposits;

}

public List<Withdrawal> getWithdrawals() {
    Collections.sort(withdrawals, new Comparator<Operation>(){
        public int compare (Operation a, Operation b){
            return (int) (b.getValue() - a.getValue());
        }
    });
    return withdrawals;
}
```

the first one returns a List ordered by date, while getDeposits() and getWithdrawals() return List and List ordered by value..
Could you please suggest how to make it work without mistakes and failures?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What "mistakes and failures" do you have?

Comment: I don't have any mistake but it doesn't sorting

Comment: It's basically just an improved version of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32536654/4125191). Please don't ask the same question twice. If you have improvements, you can add them as edits to the original question. But most importantly, you're not explaining where you have a problem.

Comment: @ValentinaMancuso You did ask us, "how to make it work without _mistakes and failures_". Now you say, you don't have any mistakes. Sorry, what exactly are you trying to ask? I'm voting to close as unclear ...

Comment: I'm confused - why do you have `value` as an `int` in `Deposit` and as a `double` in `Withdrawal`?  That seems like a mistake to me.  Also, storing dates as `int` is a bit odd, but possible.  Do you have an example of a case where this actually fails?  Because it looks to me like it should sort your objects, but maybe not in the way you expect.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this `-` use `compareTo(...)` method which is both on `Double` and `Date`, so for example:

```
Collections.sort(withdrawals, new Comparator<Operation>(){
    public int compare (Operation a, Operation b){
        return Double.valueOf(b.getValue()).compareTo(Double.valueOf(a.getValue()));
    }
});
```

Still, your code should work, except for some weird data you can have there... But not for real life data I think
EDIT: I was wrong, your code would only work if difference between doubles would be over 1.

Comment: Actually, there is a `Double.compare(double,double)` which would make this a lot more readable. And OP code won't work for numbers like `20.65` vs. `20.45`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic well yeah, sure you're right. But on Date there is not if I remember correctly, so I just wanted to make it work in both cases the same way to keep it simple ;) It won't. Hmmm... guess my bad.

Comment: Note that the dates in that class are `int`, not `Date`.